# CFG with regular expression terminals on RHS

Tags: regular-expressions, automata

Suppose that we expand our idea of context free grammar rules to allow regular expressions of terminals on the right hand side. For example, consider $G_1$:

$\begin{align*}
S & \rightarrow (a \mid b) S (c \mid d) \\
S & \rightarrow (a \mid b) A (c \mid d) \\
A & \rightarrow (f \mid g)^*
\end{align*}
$

Then the language of $G_1$ is the following:
$$L(G_1) = \{(a \mid b)^n (f \mid g)^* (c \mid d)^n \mid n > 0\}$$

Give a standard CFG that has the same language as $G_1$, is your grammar weakly equivalent to $G_1'$, strongly equivalent to $G_1'$, or both? Why?

Secondly, how can I transform any CFG with regular expressions of terminals on the right hand side to a normal context free grammar?

Comment: These questions have been answered dozens of times in SO. If you're going to post homework, you should at least post your best attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The general answer is pretty straightforward: if you have a grammar rule of the form $S \rightarrow {\alpha}r{\beta}$, where $r$ is a regular expression over the set of nonterminals, change this production to $S \rightarrow {\alpha}S'{\beta}$, find a right-regular grammar with start symbols $S'$ generating $L(r)$ (there is an algorithm for this); and then your grammar will include all those productions as well. Repeat for every production containing a regular expression on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 1):

A exactly grammar equivalent to **G1**  is following ( say G2) :

```
S → X S Y 
S → X A Y 

X → a | b 
Y → c | d

A → fA | gA | ^
```

Where `^`  is a null symbol (epsilon)

exactly equivalent means L(**G1**) = L(**G2**) that is language of G1 and G2 are same( *every string in L(**G1**) also in L(**G2**) and vise-versa*).